# iframe tab facebook app displays on a new page instead of within the iframe/facebook-canvas

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-oauth

I am using Python and a javascript or php sdk.

To obtain the access_token - I follow the steps indicated on the docs page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). I pass the redirect url to dialog/oauth and obtained the access_token. Once this is done, all output html being sent back to the browser gets rendered into to a new page, leaving the facebook iframe/canvas. (fyi, all output is done thru the usual 'self.response.out.write' function call).

Seems the PHP sdk hides this and I can't find a way to get : http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s" dialog to send the output from the redirected url to the iframe/canvas that triggered the application. This is a 'Page Tab' app (not a 'App on Facebook') so have set the "Page Tab Name" and "Page Tab Url" on the basic apps config page.

I have not implemented session yet and I am wondering if that is necessary to pass the iframe target as a state variable and have it passed back along with the redirect to the uri.

I have searched many posts/etc and no luck and any help would be much appreciated !!

Comment: After some more research - http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s gets redirected to an enhanced Permissions dialog (see blog http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/378/). This might be forcing the dialog to show up as a new page as opposed to a new dialog on the original fb iframe/canvas that launced the app. Hence the redirects from here are going to the new page, outside of FB canvas. There is a way to disable the enhanced permissions dialog, but I was not able to stop the permissions dialog from showing up. Continueing to struggle with this.. any help welcomed.

Comment: finally after looking at php sdk - figured out this grossly undocumented issue on the FB pages.  /* 
     * If user first time authenticated the application facebook
     * redirects user to baseUrl, so I checked if any code passed
     * then redirect him to the application url 
     * -mahmud
     */
    if (isset($_GET['code'])){
        header("Location: " . $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']);
        exit;
    }
    //~~ basically you have to do a redirect or header to the original fanpage and trigger the app again. This invokes the url with the signed_request and necessary data to move forward.

Comment: Right now , I am having difficulty getting this to work on production (it works with local:8080, however once on the web, fb is not sending the sign_request after the redirect (header call)).. Continuing to research. Will post in details all findings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab Page Application undocumented steps :

1. The confusing part is the CANVAS_PAGE_URL in the example. This needs to be the web-hosted app URL (e.g. https://www.appname.appspot.com/).. This not clearly defined..
2. If access_token and the user_id is not found on the signed_request an auth dialog needs to be done (as per the page documentation). This needs to be done thru the script top.location.ref to endure that it launches as a dialog. This goes to a new page overwriting the canvas (or the fan-page) that triggered the app.
3. When the user allows the permissions on the app, the app is called thru the tab-page-canvas-url?code=".....". At this point, a redirect needs to be done (which is not documented anywhere. I had to look at the php sdk code to figure this out (fbmain.php line 17) (redirect() in python and header() php). The redirect needs to take the url for the app on the fan page : http://www.facebook.com/FAN_PAGE_NAME?sk=app_nnnnnnn

It took many hours of research and digging to understand this and hope it helps (I see a lot of questions raised around page breaking out of the iframe/canvas) and the basic problem is the extra redirect step that FB does not document anywhere...

(mail me and I am happy to share python code that is now all working nicely)

Answer (score 0):

It is stated elsewhere, but to make clear: the reason your app breaks out of facebook is because the authentication dialogs get away from the original apps.facebook.com url.

This may only happen with extended permissions as the new permissions screen is two pages instead of one.

Once the authorization process is complete, the browser is redirected to the fully qualified app url on your server.

The "fix" is to send the browser back to the Facebook app using it's http://apps.facebook.com/appname address.

[that doesn't seem like good "flow" to most people, but that is how it is right now. I think there may be a different route by using the "Authenticated Referrals" on the "Auth Dialog" page of the apps, but haven't used it yet]

I use the PHP SDK and here is what I do:

1. Check for the "state" request parameter when your redirct_url is called after authorization. Some people had suggested using the "code" parameter, but I do not see it being returned.

''

```
// after completing the first authorization, the redirect url may send users away from Facebook to the redirect url itself.    
//This php code redirects them back to the app page

if (isset($_GET['state'])){ header("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/appname']); exit; }
```

If you know a better way, please let me know!